# How can i make an image appear to the right of text?

Tags: html, css, image

This is my first time using html.
Im trying to replicate the look in this image :
https://prnt.sc/1152ms5
This is what im stuck on:
https://prnt.sc/1152n3s

Ive used float right, and float left to get my image to be to the right of my paragraph, but i cant get it to start at the top of the page. (if that makes sense)
I think my issue is the img colliding with some sort of border from  ("Bem vindo")

Here is my html and css mess:
https://prnt.sc/1152non
https://prnt.sc/1152o40

Comment: Do read [ask] as this question will likely be closed in its current state.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add style to your section and display it in block way, the same for your image.

```html
<section style="padding: 2rem; background-color: grey; display: block; float: left; height: 500px; color: white">
  <h1>SOME CONTENT</h1>
</section>
<img style="display: block; float: left; width: 50%;" src="https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/best-press-release-example.jpg" alt=""/>
```